# Split datetime range on a specific date into 2 records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's give a datetime `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` (midnight of 22 April 2019)

Now I have a table of records that contains a StartDate and EndDate

```
ID          StartDate                         EndDate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           2019-04-15 00:00:00.000           2019-04-18 00:00:00.000
2           2019-04-16 00:00:00.000           2019-04-28 00:00:00.000
3           2019-04-23 00:00:00.000           2019-04-25 00:00:00.000
```

How can I split record with ID = 2 so that I get two records:

- record one start date: `2019-04-16 00:00:00.000` and end date: `2019-04-21 23:59:59.000`
- record two start date: `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` and end date: `2019-04-28 00:00:00.000`

Basically if a range has the start date before `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` and end date after `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` then split that record into two records where the end date will be midnight before `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` for the first record and start date will become `2019-04-22 00:00:00.000` for the second record.

Comment: I'd do a UNION ALL. First SELECT all datetimes until given timestamp, the other SELECT from that timestamp.

Comment: you can Use DATEADD(ms, -3, '2019-04-22')

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a `UNION ALL`, where the first `SELECT` returns all rows starting before given datetime, and the second `SELECT` returns all rows ending after that datetime. Something like:

```
select id, startdate, case when EndDate < '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000' then EndDate
                           else '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000' end EndDate
from tablename
where startdate < '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000'

UNION ALL

select id, case when startdate > '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000' then startdate
                else '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000' end,
        EndDate
from tablename
where EndDate > '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000'
```

The `case` expressions are there to adjust start or end time for the overlapping rows, those who are splitted into two separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
DECLARE @splitDate DATE = '2019-04-22 00:00:00.000';

SELECT ID, StartDate, (select min(i) from (values (test.EndDate), (@splitDate)) AS T(i)) AS EndDate 
FROM table_name WHERE StartDate < @splitDate
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, (select max(i) from (values (test.StartDate), (@splitDate)) AS T(i)) AS StartDate, EndDate 
FROM table_name WHERE EndDate > @splitDate
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e51ce597879c843b4c9d62c867c7171)